# How to search for specific content inside round bracktes and put it into a group?

Tags: regex, notepad++, regular-language

I want to update round about 3000 sql scripts where I either have this

```
ALTER TABLE `database_name`.`table_name` 
ADD INDEX `index_name` (`column_name` ASC); /* or DESC */
```

or this

```
ALTER TABLE `database_name`.`table_name` ADD INDEX `index_name` (`column_name` ASC); /* or DESC */
```

I'm using Notepad++ and want to replace both cases with a procedure. First of all this is what I have tried so far to find both cases

```
ALTER TABLE `?(.*)`?.`?(.*)`? ADD INDEX `?(.*)`? \([^\),]+\);
```

and currently I'm missing the case for multiple lines. I'm not sure where to check for multiple lines, when adding a `\n` before `ADD` there will be no hits.

The procedure will always be

```
CALL my_proc('database_name', 'table_name', 'column_name', 'index_name');
```

This is what I tried so far to replace it

```
CALL my_proc($1, $2, ..., $3);
```

Unfortunately I don't know the correct pattern to use for `...` I basically want to say: Only extract the column name from what's inside the round brackets.

How do I have to modify my search regex take care for multiple lines and put the `column_name` into a fourth group so that I can use this

```
CALL my_proc($1, $2, $4, $3);
```

Comment: Do you need to replace the input `\`` with `'`?

Comment: hm no, I think the backticks are fine, the SQL works with them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base on your work, you can try:

```
ALTER TABLE `?([^.`]+)`?.`?([^.`]+)`?(?: | ?\n| ?\r\n)ADD INDEX `?([^.`]+)`? \(`?([^.`]+)`.*\);
```

And replace with:

```
CALL my_proc\(`$1`, `$2`, `$4`, `$3`\);
```

Explanations on the regex:

```
`?([^.`]+)`?
```

Means:

- zero or one backtick
- a capturing group with anything else than a `.` or a backtick one or unlimited times
- zero or one backtick

Then a `.` then the same pattern

- `(?: | ?\n| ?\r\n)` means a non capturing group with a space OR zero or one space followed by a Unix new line OR zero or one space followed by a Windows new line
- etc.

Explanations on the replace: the parenthesis have to be escaped, and based on what you've done, the backticks must be added manually

Example: https://regex101.com/r/QKPYsX/3